# mysql dynamic queries without clause where

Tags: php, mysql

In the following example there is a base query. Other *parameters* can be dynamically added to complete the query.

However, my base query has no clause WHERE.

What is the best way to deal with it.

If I use in the base query, for example, **WHERE 1 = 1**, it seems to solve, but I have some doubts that is a correct solution.

```
$myQuery = "SELECT fr.oranges, fr.aplles, fr.bananas,
            FROM fruits fr
            LEFT JOIN countrys ct ON fr.id_fruit = ct.id_fruit";


if(!empty($countrys){
     $myQuery .= " AND countrys = ? ";
}

 if(!empty($sellers){
     $myQuery .= " AND seller = ? ";
}

 $myQuery .=" GROUP BY fr.id_fruit ORDER BY fr.fruit ASC";
```

Edited: I fixed a writing gap from $empty to empty.

Comment: checkout this question https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7983/does-where-1-1-usually-have-an-impact-on-query-performance

Comment: 1. A WHERE clause is no longer required. 
2. Adding WHERE 1=1 is OK

Comment: Thanks Ali, ryantxr and symcbean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WHERE 1=1` is a simplistic hack that works well because it simplifies your code. There is a great post [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33937/good-bad-or-indifferent-where-1-1) which explains the performance implications of `WHERE 1=1`. The general consensus is it will have no effect on performance.

Also, slight note (`$empty`) is probably not a function you've defined. I think you want [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php). You could write it like this:

```
$myQuery = "SELECT fr.oranges, fr.aplles, fr.bananas,
            FROM fruits fr
            LEFT JOIN countrys ct ON fr.id_fruit = ct.id_fruit";

$where = [];
if(!empty($countrys){
     $where[] = "countrys = ?";
}

if(!empty($sellers){
     $where[] = "seller = ?";
}

if (!empty($where)) {
    $myQuery .= " WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $where);
}

$myQuery .= " GROUP BY fr.id_fruit ORDER BY fr.fruit ASC";
```

Comment: Indeed this makes life a lot more simple - but you can even even just use "WHERE 1"

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array to control your SQL like this:

```
$where = [];
if(!$empty($countrys){
    $where[] = " countrys = ? ";
}

if(!$empty($sellers){
    $where[] = " seller = ? ";
}

if(count($where) > 0) {
    $myQuery .= " WHERE ".implode('AND', $where);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Filipe.